# In my pagination program, why page link can't show properly

Tags: php, pagination

Following is my code.
In my html file,

```
<html>
...
    <body>
        .....
        <?php 
            for($i=1;$i<=$pages;++$i) { ?>
       <a href="pagination?pages=" <?php echo $i;?> > <?php echo $i ;?></a>
           <?php } 
       ?>
    </body>
<html>
```

the first `<?php echo $i;?>` can't work properly , so every page link shows "pagination?pages=".
What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are closing the href="" to early. Try this:

```
<?php for($i=1;$i<=$pages;++$i) { ?>
    <a href="pagination?pages=<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i ;?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted generates an invalid anchor tag. You might as well make the whole thing a single PHP block; it will make your syntax a little cleaner:

```
<?php 
    for($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
        echo '<a href="pagination?pages=$i">$i</a>';
    } 
?>
```

The above ensures that `$i` gets included in your URL. Where does `$pages` come from?

Comment: $pages is a varible caluated before . Your code can't work properly because I think "$i" is in a '' context , so it is treated as a string instead of a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Te problem is:`for($i=1;$i<=$pages;++$i)`   , $i starts in 2
should be:
    `for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++)`.
Check [this link](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/operators.php)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't quit understand what you mean.